# Display Data Based on Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

How would I go about using c# and ASP.NET (or Javascript if need be) to have my drop down lists change something like a div on the page. Basically I want it to populate a div with certain data.Either from a SQL or XML Data Source. I have places I wanted listed, so I'm assuming I'm going to need to put each place in with the tags that it may contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jQuery, or some other javascript library, to hook up a listener to your dropdown and when the value changes I would make a request to some services or where you get your data from.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using asp.net, then it's really straight-forward.

1) put a `<asp:label>` or `<asp:literal>` in your div.
2) in your designer, double-click your dropdownlist -- this will take you to the code-behind for the dropdown's onselecteditemchanged event.
3) Call your data, and assign it to the label.  Ex.: ...me.myLabel.text = myreader("myfield"), or some more complicated html you've assembled, or what have you.